# Google Drive integration lost in 16.10

Tags: nautilus, google-drive

When I had 16.04, I used the Google Drive integration feature described [here on OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/use-google-drive-ubuntu-16-04-linux-desktops)

Since upgrading to 16.10, with Nautilus 3.20.3, that feature seems to have disappeared. It was there on one occasion, but I haven't seen it since, nor have I found an obvious way of getting it back even though I've activated it in Gnome Control Center.

Has the feature been lost with the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [gvfs-backends](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/gvfs-backends) package. You can install it with the command `sudo apt install gvfs-backends`

Comment: I already have gvfs-backends installed.